# python2.6 with MySQLdb, NameError 'MySQLdb' not defined

Tags: python, mysql, programming-languages, network-programming

from the interpreter i can issue >>> from MySQLdb just fine. so, I'm assuming the module did actually load. My source looks as follows:

> from Tkinter import *
>   from MySQLdb import *
>   """
>   Inventory control for Affordable Towing
>
> Functions:
>   connection() - Controls database connection
>   delete() - Remove item from database
>   edit() - Edit item's attributes in database
>   lookup() - Lookup an item
>   new() - Add a new item to database
>   receive() - Increase quantity of item in database
>   remove() - Decrease quantity of item in database
>   report() - Display inventory activity
>   transfer() - Remove item from one location, receive item in another
>
> """
>   def control():
>   ....dbInfo = { 'username':'livetaor_atowtw', 'password':'spam', \
>   ....'server':'eggs.com', 'base':'livetaor_towing', 'table':'inventory' }
>   ....def testConnection():
>   ........sql = MySQLdb.connect(user=dbInfo[username], passwd=dbInfo[password], \
>   ........host=dbInfo[server], db=dbInfo[base])
>   ........MySQLdb.mysql_info(sql)
>
> ....testConnection()
>
> control()

this gives me:

> brad@brads-debian:~/python/towing/inventory$ python inventory.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ..File "inventory.py", line 53, in 
>   ....control()
>   ..File "inventory.py", line 26, in control
>   ....testConnection()
>   ..File "inventory.py", line 22, in testConnection
>   ....sql = MySQLdb.connect(user=dbInfo[username], passwd=dbInfo[password], \
>   NameError: global name 'MySQLdb' is not defined

1) where am I going wrong?
2) any other gotcha's that you folks see?
3) any advice on how to check for a valid connection to the database, (not just the server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the way you're importing the module and then referencing it.

Change:

```
from MySQLdb import *
```

to

```
import MySQLdb
```

if you plan on referencing it the fashion that you are.

Anyway, here’s how these statements and functions work:

From:  http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

import X imports the module X, and creates a reference to that module in the current namespace. Or in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can use X.name to refer to things defined in module X.

from X import * imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to all public objects defined by that module (that is, everything that doesn’t have a name starting with “_”). Or in other words, after you’ve run this statement, you can simply use a plain name to refer to things defined in module X. But X itself is not defined, so X.name doesn’t work. And if name was already defined, it is replaced by the new version. And if name in X is changed to point to some other object, your module won’t notice.

from X import a, b, c imports the module X, and creates references in the current namespace to the given objects. Or in other words, you can now use a and b and c in your program.

Comment: my week, feeble mind forgot about the import, and the way it affects namespace. Thanks for reminding me of how much of an idiot I am. Your explanations were far above average! I'll *try* not to forget this lesson again.

Answer (score 1):

`from MySQLdb import *` and `import MySQLdb` do *very* different things.